# Why isn't this converting correctly?

Tags: javascript, math

This is suppose to return the converted number as a whole number. That part works but it doesn't turn the right conversion.

```
var input = prompt('Please enter your temp in fahrenheit');

function converter (){
   var x = Math.round(input - 32 * 5/9);
   console.log(x);
   return x;
}
alert('The temp in celsius is: ' + converter());
```

Comment: Remember BODMAS, BEDMAS Or PEDMAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius is T(°C) = (°F - 32) × 5/9. You run into an order of operations issue. This should work.

```
var input = prompt('Please enter your temp in fahrenheit');

function converter (){
   var x = Math.round((input - 32) * 5/9);
   console.log(x);
   return x;
}
alert('The temp in celsius is: ' + converter());
```

Comment: @itajenglish Awesome! Happy to help you out. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the paranthesis , which forced the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to take over the calculation.

```js
var input = prompt('Please enter your temp in fahrenheit');

function converter() {
  var x = Math.round((input - 32) * 5 / 9);
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}
alert('The temp in celsius is: ' + converter());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
(input - 32) * (5 / 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't correctly converting because of operator precedence, JavaScript operator precedence goes from highest (20) to lowest (0), Multiplication/Division has a precedence of 14 and Subtraction has a precedence of 13, so parenthesis (precedence 20) is required to mark which expression should execute first.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#celsius').on('input', function (event) {
    var celsius = $('#celsius').val();
    var fahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);
    $('#fahrenheit').val(fahrenheit);
  });
  
  $('#fahrenheit').on('input', function (event) {
    var fahrenheit = $('#fahrenheit').val();
    var celsius = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
    $('#celsius').val(celsius);
  });
  
  function celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius) {
    if (celsius === undefined || celsius === null) {
      return celsius;
    }
    
    var fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32;
    
    return fahrenheit.toFixed(5);
  }
  
    function fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit) {
    if (fahrenheit === undefined || fahrenheit === null) {
      return fahrenheit;
    }
    
    var celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9;
      
    return celsius.toFixed(5);
  }
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Celsius</label>
  <input type="text" id="celsius"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Fahrenheit</label>
  <input type="text" id="fahrenheit"/>
</div>
```